# GitHub API repository search, not getting complete json response in Android

Tags: android, github, github-api

I am trying to develop an android application, to test with Github API functionalities.

For searching repositories based on the query string below url is used

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=json%20parser&sort=stars&order=desc

When you open this url in the browser, we can able to see complete json in the browser.
But am trying to download the same json content in the Android app using asynhttpclient, retrofit and other ways. But not able to get complete json, alwasy it gives incomplete json (partial response body).

Can any one please help on this?

Comment: Could this be an issue with Logcat? It has a limit to how much it can display..

Comment: Tried converting to json before displaying, then I got json parsing error.